# Python - Parse JSON results

Tags: json, python-3.x

How do I parse the below JSON results to print out what I need?

{
"data": {
"abuseConfidenceScore": 100,
"countryCode": "ZW",
"domain": "dandemutande.co.zw",
"hostnames": [
"ip-net-196-43-114-234.africaonline.co.zw"
],
"ipAddress": "196.43.114.234",
"ipVersion": 4,
"isPublic": true,
"isWhitelisted": false,
"isp": "Africa Online Zimbabwe",
"lastReportedAt": "2021-06-19T10:32:46+00:00",

I want to print out the **"abuseConfidenceScore"** and **"isWhitelisted"** objects.

The output should be like:

abusedConfidenceScore 100

isWhitelisted false

Essentially, I want to print an object (abuseConfidenceScore) within an object (data) rather than the whole object (data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good approach to these type of problems is to first check the depth of json , and by depth I mean , how many dictionaries are nested,so after loading the dict would be,

```py
{'data': {'abuseConfidenceScore': 100, 'countryCode': 'ZW', 'domain': 'dandemutande.co.zw', 'hostnames': ['ip-net-196-43-114-234.africaonline.co.zw'], 'ipAddress': '196.43.114.234', 'ipVersion': 4, 'isPublic': True, 'isWhitelisted': False, 'isp': 'Africa Online Zimbabwe', 'lastReportedAt': '2021-06-19T10:32:46+00:00'}}
```

here, depth = 2 dicts
thus, we are gonna make a double loop and check for your required keys

```py
f = {'data': {'abuseConfidenceScore': 100, 'countryCode': 'ZW', 'domain': 'dandemutande.co.zw', 'hostnames': ['ip-net-196-43-114-234.africaonline.co.zw'], 'ipAddress': '196.43.114.234', 'ipVersion': 4, 'isPublic': True, 'isWhitelisted': False, 'isp': 'Africa Online Zimbabwe', 'lastReportedAt': '2021-06-19T10:32:46+00:00'}}
for first_dict_keys in f.keys():
     if first_dict_keys == 'data':
         for second_dict_key_val in f['data'].items(): #will return a tuple of key and value
              if second_dict_key_val[0] in ['abuseConfidenceScore','isWhitelisted']: #since they both are in the same dict
                 print(f'{second_dict_key_val[0]} {second_dict_key_val[1]}')
```

hope it helped you :D

well you can sepratae those words in the string only if they are in camel case like in this one

```py
x = 'abuseConfidenceScore'
def camel_case_parser(s):
     res = ''
     for char in s:
          if char.islower():
               res += char
          else:
               res += f' {char}'
     return res
print(camel_case_parser(x))
```

Comment: Beautiful, thank you! Is there a way that I can change the key names, such as 'abuseConfidenceScore' to 'Abuse Confidence Score'?